# PHP cost calculator HOW

Tags: php, jquery, calculator

i´m pretty new to php so im stuck with a easier calculator script...well... not easy to me but at least it doesnt sound too complicated.

firstly, i need to create a calculator that has 2 inputs... a dropdown list with cars (4 of them) that each of has a value (price per kilometer) and a textbox that user fills with a kilometer value (how many km´s he wants to drive). Then the output should be with jquery (live result). Operation is, of course, multiplying.

i would really appreciate if someone could help me out in this. im good at html and css but totally out of php.

```
<div class="styled-select"> 
  <select name="dropdown"> 
    <option value="<?=$car1;?>">Mercedes</option> 
    <option value="<?=$car2;?>">Scania</option> 
    <option value="<?=$car3;?>">Renault</option> 
    <option value="<?=$car4;?>">MAN</option> 
  </select> </div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: sure, I can help you out. What do you need exactly?

Comment: Well... i have a dropdown menu, text box and result (output) ... i have also styled them in css but i have no idea how to transform it to a full working calculator like i described before... pretty hard without any experience but good practise though :)

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Filling in the value?  Performing the calculation?  This doesn't actually need PHP, just javascript.

Comment: @Jason McCreary

`<div class="white_wrap">
    
    <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="<?=$car1;?>">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="<?=$car2;?>">Scania</option>
        <option value="<?=$car3;?>">Renault</option>
        <option value="<?=$car4;?>">MAN</option>
    </select>

<textarea name="text" cols="20" rows="1" id="km"></textarea>

<div id="output" class="border-bottom""><p class="bold">0</p></div>

</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

HTML

```
<input id="distance"/>
<select name="dropdown" id="cars">/* options*/
<input id="result"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#cars, #distance').on('keyup change',function(){
        var dist=$('#distance').val();  
        var car=$('#cars').val();
        var res=  dist * car ;
        $('#result').val( res || 0 );
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/d8ETu/

Comment: Jes Jes jes, thanks you so much! I really appreciate it :) And thank you all who commented also :)

Comment: One more question: How to put the result id into p brackets and make a default value of result 0 (visible when no values inserted in distance id) ??? Doesnt seem to work in as paragraph...

Comment: `val()` is used for form eleemnts... use `text()` for a `p` tag or `span` or `div` etc